# Add space within foreach elements

Tags: php

i have two foreach operations like below.

```
    $sql = "select region_name from ".$GLOBALS['ecs']->table('region') . " where region_id in(".$order['province'].",". $order['city'].",".$order['district'].")";
    $address = $GLOBALS['db']->getAll($sql);
    foreach($address as $vo){
        $region .= $vo['region_name'];
    }
    $order['1address'] = $region.$order['1address'];
    return $order;
}
```

Here's a sample of the output data:

> AlabamaColorado

How i want it to be

> Alabama Colorado

The only thing wrong is I could not separate Alabama and Colorado with blank space. It might be an easy operation but how? Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: $region .= " ".$vo['region_name'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if ($region == '') {
    $region = $vo['region_name'];
} else {
    $region .= ' ' . $vo['region_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this without foreach,

```
$region = explode(' ', array_column($address, 'region_name'));
$order['1address'] = $region . $order['1address'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by concatenating a space between your `$region` and `$order['1address']` variables.

The snippet below illustrates how you can achieve that:

```
$order['1address'] = $region . " " . $order['1address'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I prefer to use an array and then [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it:

```
// initialize the array to avoid NOTICES
$region = array();
foreach ( $address AS $vo ) {
    // add each region name to a new element in the array
    $region[] = $vo['region_name'];
}

// implode the regions array to a string separated by a space
$region = implode( ' ', $region );
```